# Parsing iometer results

Tags: parsing, iometer

How do your visualise your iometer results?

Answer (score 2):

I don't, I use [IOZone](http://www.iozone.org/), which I prefer and has all sorts of nice ways to visualise it;

[image]
<sub>(source: [iozone.org](http://www.iozone.org/docs/read.jpg))</sub>

Sure is purdy eh!

Comment: +1 for the purdy graph alone.